# Simple HTML Dom modify class attribute with multiple classes

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I tried to declare multiple class names to an single DOM element by using SimpleHTMLDom.php. It is known that the selection of multiple classes only works, if each class name starts with dot (.) and the blanks are removed. Is there a similar trick for setting attributs?

Here is an example code:

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = str_get_html('<div>foo</div>');
$html->setAttribute('class', 'classA classB');
// <div class="classA" classB="">foo</div>

$html->class = 'classA classB';
// <div class="classA" classB="">foo</div>
```

How can I get `<div class="classA classB">foo</div>`?

Maybe Simple HTML Dom is not the best way to do such things. I would also appreciate suggestions for any alternatives.

Comment: I found the solution myself. I used 'ganon' instead. `$html->setAttribute('class','classA classB');` does the job.